# Are air mice unable to wake a computer from s3?

Tags: usb, mouse, sleep

I built a htpc and am happy with it, there are no problems. I have a cheap microsoft USB wireless keyboard and mouse that I use to control it. Recently I have been looking at air-mice to replace them. Every air-mouse of the three that I have bought has worked fine as a controller except in one regard; they will not wake the htpc after it has been put to sleep (both s3 and s1 power states).

When I connect an air-mouse to any other computer I have access to it is also unable to wake that computer. The computers all have different hardware and run both windows and linux and are not affected in any other way. When I connect my wireless keyboard and mouse to any of these computers they are able to wake it up fine.  The air-mice and the wireless keyboard and mouse superficially seem to use similar USB receivers.

I am at loss as to why these very similar bits of hardware should differ on this one function. Is there a reason for this? Is there any simple thing I am overlooking to get an air-mouse to wake a computer?

If no one has an explanation can someone at least recommend an air-mouse that they *know* would wake from s3?

UPDATE: I've run out of time if I want to return the air-mice so I won't be able to carry on troubleshooting but thanks for everyone's help anyway. If I buy another, I will only get one I know for certain wakes from s3.

Comment: Could you post some more information on the the computers you try to wake? you Said "htpc" im guessing Home Theater Personal Computer. Now from what you are saying is that once you built this now you cannot wake any of the other Pcs up? or could you better explain exactly what is going on.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Sorry for the confusion. All computers are fine and not being affected by the air-mice. I'd like to know why every air-mouse I use (and presumably all air-mice) lacks the ability to wake a computer from s3. I edited my question and hope this clarifies things.

Comment: One other thing real quick that I should have asked before what are the Air Mice you have tried so far? Sorry for the late reply I work at night.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin the air mice I've tried are; [MeLE F10 Deluxe](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B018K7CO1M?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00), [JUSTOP F20](http://www.justop.com/catalog/justop-f20-3d-smart-air-mouse-controller-keyboard-with-ir-remote-leaning.html) and [Rii i25](http://www.riitek.com/goods/detail/54.htm) appologies for the late response.

Comment: What have you tried?  How do you fix it?  (e.g., power off computer?  restart computer? remove USB receiver and plug it back in?)  I have one wireless mouse that seems unresponsive, after it sleeps, until a mouse button is pressed.  (It ignores movement.)  But after a single click, it works just fine (until it sleeps again).

Comment: @TOOGAM The air-mice work as they are supposed to before the computer sleeps and after the computer wakes. Removing the USB reciever and plugging it back in while the computer is asleep does not change anything i.e. any input from the air-mouse will not wake the computer.

Answer (score 1):

An idea: based on the comments, it sounds like the issue is just with one computer while it is asleep.  The problem is not with the mouse.

Basically, the problem is that the computer's USB port is unresponsive when the computer is asleep.  (I'm assuming these "air mice" are wireless mice using USB receivers; if not, just adjust my comment as appropriate.)  This problem won't be affected by changing to a different USB-based mouse.

- Check BIOS settings.  See if S1 instead of S3 works.  Maybe even see if there are compatibility settings to be more compatible with "Legacy" protocols/hardware.
- Try different USB ports (probably unlikely, but possible).
- See if there is a BIOS upgrade available.  Such upgrades are sometimes known to change behaviors, possibly by adding options/settings.
- Check the operating system's power settings related to sleeping/hibernation/expansion ports/USB, just in case.

You might not be able to do exactly what you hope for.  e.g., if S1 works and S3 doesn't, then that may be by design (at least for this particular unit), and perhaps a BIOS update is the only hope for an easy "fix" in that case.

(I'm using the term "BIOS".  Of course, if your system uses (U)EFI, then make the appropriate upgrade.)

Comment: Thanks for the response, sry about the late reply. I've tried using the air-mice on different computers with different hardware, BIOS settings and Operating Systems. Also they won't wake from S1 (which I don't think I would be satisfied with anyway). I've run out of time if I want to return the air-mice so I won't be able to carry on troubleshooting but thanks for your help anyway. If I buy another, I will only get one I _know for certain_ wakes from s3.

Comment: Hi p2a, have you find any solution? What air-mouse you know can wake from s3, please?